# Menu DIV not getting 100% of the window

Tags: html, css, width, navbar

My site in mobile layout (`max-width: 767px`) has a collapse menu as you can see [here](http://ahseamodapega.provisorio.ws/)

But before was `100%` of the window and now it isn't getting full `width` anymore.

My CSS for collapse menu is:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    background: #cfcfcf;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Any idea of what could have caused this "bug"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .navbar-collapse element's parent has a width of zero. Set width:100%; on it's parent element (#ItensMenuFixoTop) and it should be fixed. Setting a width as percentage will be relative to the item's parent, not the window.

Comment: Problem solved....Thank you! I've been working on it for more than an hour and I didn't realize it!!!! It was so simple.... but CSS is still kinda tricky for me....